# Binary operation $xy$, has identity, but not associativity. Is the inverse unique?

Tags: abstract-algebra, binary-operations

Let $S$ be a set with a binary operation $xy$ defined on it, with a neutral element, but not satisfying associativity. I want to prove that the inverse isn't necessarily unique.

My attempt to answer this is in the answer below.

Comment: Presumably, you mean, when an inverse exists? Is the neutral element both a right and left neutral element?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yes, that is the only way I know it so far

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $S=\{1,2,3\}$ and define $\star$ so that $x\star 1 = 1\star x=x$ and $x\star y=1$ if $x,y\in\{2,3\}$.  Then $(S,\star)$ has a neutral element, $1$, but $2\star 3=2\star 2=1$, so inverse elements are not unique.

Comment: What is $f$? There is no $f$ here. It is a binary operation on a set with an identity.

Comment: @MakotoK. No, the map is $S\times S\to S$ (since it is a binary operation).

Comment: The point is, if someone asks you whether, "Are all natural numbers even," you don't show that it is impossible to prove, you just say, "$1$ is a natural number and it is not even, so the statement is false."

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Thank you

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Oh very true! I better redo this chapter three times before moving on!!

Comment: No, since $1\star 3=3$ and $1\star 2=2$, it is not just a map to $\{1\}$. And it is not a map of $S$, it is a map of $S\times S$.

Comment: $1*1=1,1*2=2,1*3=3,2*1=2,2*2=1,2*3=1,3*1=3,3*2=1,3*3=1$ and we have $S\times S \to S$, got it

Comment: You constructed this minimally I believe. It needed one element for identity, and two more distinct elements to be both of the inverses. That is why you made it like this isn't it?

Comment: I didn't deliberately make it minimal, I just realized I couldn't do it with two elements, and was looking for something simple.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Okay that's what I thought, that helps illuminate the proper thought process, thank you once again, I will leave you alone now :).