# non unique additive inverse / non unique additive identity

Tags: abstract-algebra

Two of the properties of a vector space is the uniqueness of additive inverse and additive identity . I am trying to imagine a case outside algebra where the additive inverses/identity are not unique and I am not able to think about a case.

Comment: Assuming associativity, these must be unique. Otherwise, not necessarily: see e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1106653/binary-operation-xy-has-identity-but-not-associativity-is-the-inverse-uniqu

Comment: I do not know what you mean by "outside algebra".  A possible example would be "modulo arithmetic", depending on exactly how you think about it,  For example, in "arithmetic modulo 5" we can think of any multiple of 5 as an additive identity and  "3", "8", "13", etc, as additive inverses of "2".  Typically, of course, we think of "3" as **meaning** the set of all integers 3 more than a multiple of 5 or else we restrict "modulo 5" to the numbers 0, 1, 2, 3, and 4

Comment: @user247327, I think the modulo operation doesn't satisfy the associativity and commutativity maybe that is why it is not unique, it was a good practise to look into it

Comment: @AlexProvost interesting is there a formal proof you can point me to ?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the possibility that we have two additive identities, $0_1$ and $0_2$. By using first that $0_2$ is an additive identity and then that $0_1$ is an additive identity, we get
$$
0_1 = 0_1 + 0_2 = 0_2
$$
so whenever you have two additive identities, they are in fact the same element, as a consequence of the property we want additive identities to have.

A similar reasoning works for additive inverses: Say you have a vector $x$ and two additive inverses $y_1$ and $y_2$. Then
$$
y_1 = 0 + y_1 = x+y_2 + y_1 = x + y_1 + y_2 = 0 + y_2 = y_2
$$
and we see that the two are really the same.

So it's not really a requirement as much as a natural consequence of how we want additive identities and inverses to behave. However, *specifying* that they are unique does make it so that we don't have to do proofs like this.

As mentioned in the comments, the latter proof requires that addition is commutative and associative. There are algebraic structures where the operation is neither commutative nor associative, but then the operation wouldn't deserve the name "addition" in my opinion.

Comment: There is no need for commutativity: write instead $y_1 = 0 + y_1 = y_2 + x + y_1 = y_2 + 0 = y_2$.

Comment: @AlexProvost Of course, if we don't have commutativity, then right inverses and left inverses might be different things, so we could have $y_1$ and $y_2$ both be right inverses, for instance, and your proof wouldn't work. So there is a whole new jungle of conditions to keep track of. I went for the simple solution.